# Ошибка при установке плагина NetBeans OpenGL Pack?

Tags: установка, java, netbeans

В NetBeans 7.0.1 ставлю [вот этот плагин](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3260/netbeans-opengl-pack) - в результате ставится все, кроме GLSL editor. Получаю вот такое уведомление:

> Для некоторых подключаемых модулей необходима установка подключаемого модуля Библиотека редактора. Требуется подключаемый модуль Библиотека редактора версии >= 1.29.2.8.2 (версия выпуска 1), найденный подключаемый модуль имеет версию 3.9.1.13.10 (версию выпуска, отличную от 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве не очевидно? Ваша версия NetBeans слишком нова для этого плагина.

*PS: И вообще у меня и у многих моих знакомых складывается ощущение, что чем дальше NetBeans развивается, тем больше в нем становится багов, особенно после выхода 7.0.
Сам полгода как перешел на IDEA.*

Comment: Да спасибо, я уже разобрался, сначала думал что новые версии среди должны поддерживать старые версии плагины